# Gathering backups logs for Windows Server Backup

Tags: windows-server-2008, backup, log-files

I have a few servers running Windows Server Standard SP2, all of which are running windows server backup.  It runs daily, and I would like to receive a notification that the backups have completed successfully/Failed.

I see there is another [question(162889)](https://serverfault.com/q/162889/) which has not been answered. I use Kaseya, and have the ability to gather some data on the machine and process that into an email Kaseya can send out.

What I'm having problems with is finding the correct log, and converting the *.etl file into something readable.

I've used different mixes of tracerpt to try and get what I want, but I haven't had a readable output. The log files I'm pulling from are located in %windir%\logs\windowsserverbackup\ via [MS KB Article](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverfiles/thread/1cdb9617-7ea5-4f5a-a89a-e492a118920c)

Has anyone had any success with this?

Thanks!